# How can i remove attribute style with class fr-popup fr-desktop by froala editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, froala

I have a Froala editor that inserts an image and clicking the image opens another froala mini box for the management of the image itself. The problem is that the div tag with fr-popup fr-desktop classes have a style attribute with z-index: 5 which I can't delete. I would need to insert a greater z-index to display it, since I am now under the modal with the main editor.

```
<div class="fr-popup fr-desktop fr-above fr-active" style="z-index: 5; left: 10px; top: 213.047px;">
```

[image]

Currently to view the box I have to enter the z-index at most via the browser console.